# Why are some QGIS 2.2 bar graphs not displayed?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I created a vector layer containing all European countries and some double information about them. I'd like to show this information for every object in a bar graph. 
My problem is that the bar graphs of some areawise "big" countries (e.g. Germany, France) are not displayed in normal mode. Strangely all bar graphs are being displayed as soon as I enter the edit-mode or zoom into the countries.
I already tried all possible configurations in the bar graph menu but I can't fix it. Has anybody got an idea how to solve this problem?
I use QGIS 2.2 Valmiera.

[image: normal_mode]

[image: edit_mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off geometry simplification in the layer's rendering tab.